# How to show timepicker based jqrelcopy yii?

Tags: yii

How to show timepicker based yiibooster, with Jqrelcopy.
I've code like this :

```
<div class="control-group "><label class="control-label required">Jam Kerja</label>
         <div class="controls">
            <a id="copylink" href="#" rel=".copy">Tambah Jam Kerja / Shift</a>
            <div class="row copy">
                <?php echo CHtml::label('',''); ?>
                <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTimePicker',
                        array(
                        'name' => 'some_time',
                        'value' => '00:00',
                        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'50px'),    
                        'noAppend' => true, // mandatory
                        'options' => array(
                        'disableFocus' => true, // mandatory
                        'showMeridian' => false // irrelevant
                        ),    
                        )
                        );
                ?>
                <?php 
                    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTimePicker',
                        array(
                        'name' => 'some_time',
                        'value' => '00:00',
                        'noAppend' => true, // mandatory
                        'options' => array(
                        'disableFocus' => true, // mandatory
                        'showMeridian' => false // irrelevant
                        )
                        )
                        );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
           </div>
```

When I add new, Timepicker always on field 1. Can't on field changed.

Comment: I dont know about this jqrecopy but try changing the name to somthing different for the second one and see.

Comment: change to other extension?

Comment: Yep I would recommend doing that, would give you more control over your implementation.